# Reopen SQL developer session

Tags: database, session, client, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to know if is possible to keep the same tabs and tables open in SQL developer once you close the client. If I open a session for a DB connection and work with some tables, once I exit the program this will be all closed and when I open it again I have to start the session again and open same tables, so is a little anoying to write in notepad or somewhere which tables were open in case I have to close the client.

Is possible to keep the session and tables open once the client is closed and have it all back when is open?

Comment: No this is not possible. Files left open when your last instance of sqldev closed will be reopened, but not your connections or tables.

Comment: Oh, that's bad.....ok, thanks a lot for your help!!